# Changing title using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display every few seconds a new subtitle inside my  tag.
Here is my code:

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
       var message = ['Hello Molly','Hello Lolly','Hello Dolly'];
       
       for(var i = 0; i < message.length; i++){
           setInterval(
               $('#changed-title').text(message[i]),
               1000
           );
       }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="header">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-6 wow bounceInLeft navbar-right">
                     <h1 class="navbar-right">Hello world</h1>
                     <h2 class="navbar-right">I wanna get off</h2>
                     <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary navbar-right">More Info</button>
    
                 </div>
    
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

It's only displays the 'Hello Dolly". Basically I want the values from array to change every few seconds.How can I achieve it?

Comment: `setinterval` does not block.  By the time it runs the `i` may very well be equal to the message.length.  And actually you will have message.length -1 intervals running all at one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var messages = ['Hello Molly','Hello Lolly','Hello Dolly'];
  var index = -1;
  var $changedTitle = $('#changed-title');
  
  setInterval(function(){
    //get the message at the next index, modding by the length so it wraps
    var message = messages[++index % messages.length];
    $changedTitle.text(message);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="header">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-6 wow bounceInLeft navbar-right">
                     <h1 class="navbar-right">Hello world</h1>
                     <h2 class="navbar-right" id="changed-title">I wanna get off</h2>
                     <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary navbar-right">More Info</button>
    
                 </div>
    
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I applied your answer to my code , it's not responding, the <h2> stays the same as it is<h2> I wanna get off</h2>

Comment: Did you change the `console.log(...)` to be `$('#changed-title').text(message)` ?  Cause otherwise this is just an example of how you'd get the values in the loop

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure exactly where you wanted to put it, because there wasn't actually an element with the `id` of "changed-title" in you HTML, but, based off of your comment in the other answer, I assumed that you wanted the change in the `h2` element, so I updated it with that `id`.

Additionally, I fixed up your `setInterval` code to contain the incrementing of the counter, because, it has to happen in side the interval in order to keep in sync with it.

I also added a few other minor efficiencies into the code, as well . . . should be working now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var targetElement = $('#changed-title');
  var message = ['Hello Molly', 'Hello Lolly', 'Hello Dolly'];
  var maxIndex = message.length - 1;
  var currentIndex = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    targetElement.text(message[currentIndex]);
    currentIndex = (currentIndex === maxIndex) ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 wow bounceInLeft navbar-right">
        <h1 class="navbar-right">Hello world</h1>
        <h2 class="navbar-right" id="changed-title">I wanna get off</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary navbar-right">More Info</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The previous answer was already correct, but yours works also very well. Thank you,